# css display flex broke layout

Tags: css

I'm using flex property for my custom blockquotes, here's demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/buda9/pumZH/3/

Everything works fine when I use plain text in it. But when I add  or 
 layout isn't so nice :) I made a temporary fix by using display: block but then my icon in :before pseudo element isn't vertically aligned and I need this icon to be in the middle

```
blockquote {
    display:flex;
}
```

Trying to fix this for the last 2 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demo is little confusing, but I can tell you that this is not a good use case for `Flexbox layout`. It is not intended for things like this one. Better use old methods for this like `floats`, `absolute positioning`,etc. You need to wrap your content inside a `blockqoute` in some `block-level box` to trigger correct behavior of `flexbox layout`. 
HERO IS UPDATED DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pumZH/4/
Is this what you want ?

Comment: YES! :) that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much!